# Gradle root project depends on subprojects build

Tags: gradle, multi-project

How can I mention subproject should build before root project.

in `settings.gradle`

```
rootProject.name = 'loginmodule'
include 'servicebundle'
include 'webbundle'
include 'webredirectbundle'
```

When I try this `build dependson subprojects:build` it is giving error like circular dependency.
Currently in my root project `build.gradle` is bundling all subprojects like below

```
task createESA(type: Zip, dependsOn: generateSubSystemFile) {
    subprojects.each { dependsOn("${it.name}:build") }
    from subprojects.collect { "${it.buildDir}/libs" }
    from (subsystemFile) {
        into 'OSGI-INF'
    }
    from ('resources/OSGI-INF') {
        into 'OSGI-INF'
    }
    baseName project.name
    extension 'esa'
}

build.finalizedBy createESA
```

I am using `gradle clean build` to build the project.

Is there any better way to do that ?? I just want to build all subprojects first before root project build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `createESA` task depend on `subprojects*.build`, it'll say that task can't run until all of the `build` tasks in all of the subprojects have run. Then, declare that the root project's `build` task depends on `createESA`.

```
task createESA(type: Zip, dependsOn: subprojects*.build) {
    // etc...
}

build.dependsOn createESA
```

Comment: Finally got another way, it is only working after adding `subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
}`